# Express js error handling

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get error handling running with express but instead of seeing a response of "error!!!" like I expect I see "some exception" on the console and then the process is killed. Is this how error handing is supposed to be setup and if so is there another way to catch errors?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("error!!!");
    res.send("error!!!");
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    throw "some exception";
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on 5000");
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An example app/guide on error handling is available at 
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html
However should fix your code:

```
// Require Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(app.router); // you need this line so the .get etc. routes are run and if an error within, then the error is parsed to the next middleware (your error reporter)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(!err) return next(); // you also need this line
    console.log("error!!!");
    res.send("error!!!");
});

// Routes
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    throw "some exception";
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

// Listen
app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on 5000");
});
```

Comment: For people from the future, app.router is deprecated for the 3.x => 4.x migration process; see https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x.

Answer (score 8):

A few tips:

1) Your code wasn't working because your error handler middleware was run before your route was reached, so the error handler never had a chance to have the error passed to it. This style is known as continuation passing. Put your error handler last in the middleware stack.

2) You should shut down the server when you have an unhandled error.  The best way to do that is to call `server.close()`, where server is the result of doing `var server = http.createServer(app);`

Which means, you should do something like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log("error!!!");
  res.send("error!!!");
  server.close();
});
```

You should probably also time out the server.close(), in case it can't complete (your app is in an undefined state, after all):

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log("error!!!");
  res.send("error!!!");

  server.close();

  setTimeout(function () {
    process.exit(1);
  }, 3*1000);
});
```

I made a library that does all this for you, and lets you define custom responses, including specialized error views, static files to serve, etc...:

https://github.com/ericelliott/express-error-handler

Comment: "You should shut down the server"? Why? No! You should not!

Comment: If you have an unhandled error, you absolutely should shut down the server, because the error may leave the app in an undefined state -- meaning that things could be going wrong. Shutting down gives the app a chance to repair itself by re-starting into a stable state.

Comment: so if someone triggered an unhandled exception, the whole app will be down for everybody ? that's stupid

Comment: No. 1. You should always have a process monitoring your services and restarting them when they shut down. 2. All apps crash. Plan for it. 3. Most Node apps can restart in less than a second, and at scale, servers will be load-balanced, so other instances can pick up the slack. 4. If you do your job, crashes will be rare. 5. Running code after an unhandled exception is reckless. Your code could be doing damage, broken for everyone with no chance of self-repair. THAT is stupid. =)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and couldn't figure out what was wrong.
The thing is if you have the express errorHandler defined then your custom error handler is never being called.
If you have the next code, simply remove it:

```
if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

Worked for me:)

Answer (score 2):

Installing express install connect-domain, then something like this:

```
var express = require("express"),  
    connectDomain = require("connect-domain"),
    app = express(),
    errorHandler;
```

// Our error handler

```
app.use(connectDomain());  
    errorHandler = function (err, req, res, next) {  
        res.send(500, {
           "status": "error",
           "message": err.message
        });
    console.log(err);
};
```

Then when setting up your endpoints, tack errorHandler on the end in a use():

```
app.get("/some/data", function (req, res) {  
    // ... do some stuff ...
    res.send(200, "Yay! Happy Success!");
}).use(errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an error function:

```
function throwError(status, code, message) {
  const error = new Error(message);
  error.name = '';
  error.status = status;
  error.code = code;
  throw error;
}
```

e.g.

```
throwError(422, 'InvalidEmail', '`email` should be a valid email address')
```

We assign `name` to `''` so that when we `toString` the error it doesn't prepend it with `"Error: "`

As mentioned if you're using express you can create a special error handling middleware by specifying 4 arguments:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({ code: err.code || 'Error', message: err.toString() });
  }
});
```

If you're not using express or otherwise prefer, add that code to your `catch` handler instead.

**Why?**

1. Modern apps handle JSON, throwing errors in JSON makes more sense and results in cleaner UI code.
2. You should not only throw error messages because they are imprecise to parse. What if the UI is a multilingual app? In that case they can use the `code` to show a localized message.

Answer (score 0):

Found that recipes from here and even in official documentation brake logging for advanced loggers like `pino-http` (at least for latest express4). Problem appears when you write like this:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (!err) {
     return next();
  }
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error });
});
```

Express "thinks" that it's normal result and logger does not log error.

```
{
   ...
   "res":{"status":400},
   "msg":"request completed"
}
```

Fix here (the first line):

```
res.err = err;
res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error });
```

Log output after the fix:

```
{
   ...
   "res":{"status":400},
   "msg":"request errored",
   "err":{"type":"Error","message":"Some error","stack":"..skip.."}
}
```